# Managed dict of list not updated in multiprocessing when using += operator

Tags: python-3.x, list, dictionary, python-multiprocessing, multiprocessing-manager

Consider the following python code:

```py
from multiprocessing import Process, Manager

class MyClass():
    def __init__(self, dic1, dic2):
        self.dic1 = Manager().dict(dic1) # Create a managed dictionary
        self.dic2 = Manager().dict(dic2) # Create a managed dictionary
        process1 = Process(target=self.dictSumOverloaded, args=())
        process2 = Process(target=self.dictSumElementWise, args=())

        process1.start()
        process1.join()

        process2.start()
        process2.join()

    def dictSumOverloaded(self):
        self.dic1['1'][0] += 1 # dic1 is not updated

    def dictSumElementWise(self):
        a = self.dic2['1']
        self.dic2['1'] = [a[0]+1, a[1], a[2]] # dic2 is updated

def main():
    dic1 = {'1': [1, 0, 0]}
    dic2 = {'1': [1, 0, 0]}

    result = MyClass(dic1, dic2)
    print(result.dic1) # Failed
    print(result.dic2) # Success

    # Bypass multiprocessing environment
    dic3 = {'1': [1, 0, 0]}
    dic3['1'][0]+=1
    print(dic3) # Success

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

In this example, I create a managed dict containing a list as an attribute of `MyClass`. The goal is to increment some of the elements of this list in a multiprocessing environment, but some methods do not effectively modify the list.

**Method 1:** `dictSumOverloaded`
The overloaded operator `+=` is used to increment an element of the list by 1 but the result does not persist. The dict is not updated.
**Method 2:** `dictSumElementWise`
This function creates a new list element wise, based on the old list and the values to add. Then the new list is assigned to the dict key. The dict is successfully modified.
**Sanity check:** outside the multiprocessing environment
`dic3` is modified as expected when using `+=` outside the multiprocessing environment.

**Questions**:
1) Why is `+=` not modifying the list element in the multiprocessing environment?
2) Using the element wise method to update the list works but is cumbersome, any suggestion on making it cleaner/faster?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the problem you are encountering is related to detection of a change in the dictionary `dic1` by the anonymous `Manager` object that you create it with.

Changing the list itself with `+=` operator does not change the *reference* to the list - it is the same list, just an element of it has changed (namely 0-th element of a list stored in the thread-safe dictionary `dic1` under the key `'1'`).

With `dic2` the situation is different. With the following line:

```
self.dic2['1'] = [a[0]+1, a[1], a[2]]
```

You effectively *update* the value stored under the key `'1'`. The assigned value is a *completely new* list. It is made of elements of the list stored as the previous value under the same key but it is nevertheless a *different* list.

Such a change is detected by the `Manager` object and the reference in the process in which you check the value of `dic2` is seamlessly updated so that you could read the correct value.

The main point here is the following:

**the thread-safe collection (`dict`) does not propagate any changes to other processes (or threads) if there are no changes to keys, or values, or both. List is a reference type so the value (i.e. reference) does not change even if the list values change.**

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, too bad I did not understand that earlier. Is my dic2 method the best way to go in that case? I have not found a better/faster way to store three values in this managed dict and increment them.

Comment: Wait: the 3.7 doc says `Changed in version 3.6: Shared objects are capable of being nested. For example, a shared container object such as a shared list can contain other shared objects which will all be managed and synchronized by the SyncManager.` Does this mean that my code would be correct in version 3.6+? Of course, I have just checked and I am using Python 3.5.6

Comment: I believe this would only work if the list inside the dictionary would be created as `Manager().list`.

Comment: Could be, I have not tried. If I ever attempt using `+=` on version 3.6+ or use a managed list inside the managed dict, I'll try to remember to update this comment!